Primary constructor and IDisposable
IDE0290 suggests the use of primary constructors, but if one of the parameters happens to a IDisposable injected and you use readonly backup fields to store them, a CA2213 warning is generated
public class MyController(EfContext context)
{
  private readonly EfContext _context = context; <-- here


CA2213:    A type that implements System.IDisposable declares fields that are of types that also implement IDisposable. The Dispose method of the field is not called by the Dispose method of the declaring type. To fix a violation of this rule, call Dispose on fields that are of types that implement IDisposable if you are responsible for allocating and releasing the unmanaged resources held by the field.

However, the controller should be responsible of disposing that object. Is it a false positive?
NB: using a in parameter also gives that warning:
public class MyController(in EfContext context)
{
  private readonly EfContext _context = context; <-- here again


What's the point of using a class primary constructor and a readonly field? I would say either use only the class primary constructor and accept that it's not readonly, or use a regular constructor and readonly field.

The fact that this is a primary ctor is irrelevant I think? Tracking object ownership is hard in C#, and that analysis warning is frequently wrong. You will need to suppress it when appropriate.

I'm not sure I understand: "the controller should be responsible of disposing that object". But MyController does not implement IDisposable, so where is the context disposed? Note that a fairly common pattern is to use an optional leaveOpen parameter to indicate if another parameter should be disposed or not.

The normal code analysis heuristic is to NOT generate warning CA2213 if the disposable object is passed in via a constructor argument. It looks like that heuristic is not working for primary constructors.

@MatthewWatson isn't this a "bug"? Shouldn't CA2213 be concerned only with analyzing the contents of the Dispose` method

@IvanPetrov I assume it's a deliberate heuristic to reduce false positives. Dependency injection of disposables is quite common, and generally (not always!) the lifetime of an injected disposable is controlled from a scope outside of the injectee.

Have a read of the note for the rule

Given that note, I assert that this is an edge case that hasn't been handled and thus this is a bug in the analyser.

@MatthewWatson thanks for the link., will read. I wonder isn't this heuristic actually increasing false negatives...

@IvanPetrov I'll bet that Microsoft have tried it without that heuristic and it causes loads of false positives, with the effect that people would be likely to just disable the warning altogether. Better a few false negatives than hundreds of false positives which result in the warning being unusable.

There's some discussion about the rule here

@MatthewWatson yeah, that has to be it. I wasn't aware that "ownership" was so important with this rule.

Whether or not this is a false positive has nothing to do with the constructor or any other structural issues; the only relevant question is: what is the respective lifetimes and/or ownership-relationship between the two types. Meaning: is it your expectation that nuking a MyController should also nuke the EfContext that was injected. We can't answer that for you, but if you're using DI to provide the EfContext in a scoped way to the similarly scoped MyController, then the DI infrastructure (and in particular the scope, which will be tied to a request) has that responsibility, which means that MyController doesn't need to.
